# Dynamics CRM appointments list of a related record

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I would like to have inside a form, the Activity panel of a related record, in particular for being able to create and modify the appointments of a lead that is related to the current record. I haven't found an out-of-the-box possibility to do this (for example a quick view form), or an external addon. But I want to try to ask: is it possible, or I need to develop a web resource, if this is worth it?

Comment: Why can't you just load the associated record view and make it editable grid? I'm not sure I'm entirely following your requirements. Please explain what the requirement is, what would solving for this requirement achieves and what have you tried so far.

Comment: @Just Do It an editable grid is only possible for the relationships of the current record in the form. I think I'll propose another solution to the user, thank you.